# Form just refreshes page on submit and does not go to routes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I have been struggling with this for so long and can't figure out what the problem is. I want to just POST to `/accountRoutes/editFinalMark` and I have included the code for the route as well as the controller.

```html
<form method="post" action="/accountRoutes/editFinalMark">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="form-group" >
        <input type="" id="moduleID" name="moduleID" style="display: none;" value="<%= module._id %>">
        <input type="" name="editFinalMarkInput" id="editFinalMarkInput" class="urlInput" placeholder="Add Final Mark" style="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="editFinalMarkButton" id="editFinalMarkButton" class="submit-docs" value="Add" style="background-color: #6dabe4; border-top-right-radius: 15px; border-bottom-right-radius: 15px; color: white;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

```js
// The Route:
router.post('/editFinalMark', accountController.editFinalMark_post);
```

```js
// The Controller I want to call:
module.exports.editFinalMark_post = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { editFinalMarkInput, moduleID }  = req.body;

        console.log("\n\n\n\n\n");
        console.log("editFinalMarkInput: ", editFinalMarkInput);
        console.log("moduleID: ", moduleID);

        Module.findOneAndUpdate(
               { _id: moduleID }, 
               { $push: { final_mark: editFinalMarkInput } },
                 function (error, success) {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            console.log(success);
                        }
                }
        );



        res.status(201).json({  });


    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ err })
    }
};
```

All that happens when I click submit is that the page reloads and the url updates to include the data from the form, but it doesn't complete the action specified in the form. There are also no errors at all in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All that happens when I click submit is that the page reloads and the url updates to include the data from the form, but it doesn't complete the action specified in the form.

So it ignores both the `action` (because it goes to the wrong URL) and the `method` (because it puts the data in the URL so it is making a GET request).

From this we can infer that you have **another** `<form>` element and that is the one being submitted. You just haven't included it in the code in the question.

`<form>` elements aren't allowed to be nested so a [validator](https://validator.nu/) would help you find it.

Comment: Yes, thank you that is a big help. I didn't realise that I had nested two forms and thats why it wasn't working :)